# Is pseudo force another form of inertia observed from accelerating frame of reference?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, acceleration, inertia

We know that [pseudo forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force) act when we opt for *non-inertial frames of reference*.

Is pseudo force another form of inertia observed from *accelerating frame of reference*?

Comment: Newtons second law is F=ma; so a pseudo-force gives a pseudo-acceleration, generally.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. There is only “one type” of inertia and all objects have inertia, whether they are in an accelerating frame, or an inertial frame.

But you can say that a pseudo-force is *due* to an object's inertia
when the object moves in a non-inertial (accelerating) reference frame.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is only one form of inertia.

Thought demonstration:
Imagine a wheel-shaped space station, and the wheel is rotating such that along the rim the state of rotation is pulling 1 G of acceleration.

You are standing on the floor of the space station. The floor of the space station is exerting a force upon you to maintain your circumnavigating motion.

We extend the thought demonstration:
There are multiple parallel wheels, and inhabitants of the space station can go up to the central hub, and transit to adjacent wheels. Each wheel has a different rotation rate, so as to be pulling G's to accomodate its inhabitants.

The inhabitants transit regularly from wheel to wheel, so they have awareness of what to expect in each wheel.

Clearly, if you would live there, and you wake up from sleep, you would be aware of which wheel you are in, judging from the G-load the rotation is pulling.

Let me explain now why I have taken so much time to set up the above throught demonstration.

As an inhabitant of that space complex you have a *global* awareness of the physical nature of the space complex. When it comes to inferring where you are you are not thinking *locally*. You can tell in which wheel you are by feeling the magnitude of the G-load that is being pulled.

Of course, *locally* there is no way to tell whether the G-load that you feel is due to rotation puling G's, or due to the presence of a gravitating mass (such as a planet) However, the point is: you are not thinking *locally*; as an inhabitant of the space station you have a *global* awareness of the place.

More generally: in science, when assessing any situation, you must apply a *global* awareness. You must bring all relevant information to bear on your assessment.

Conversely, if someone asks you to restrict yourself to thinking locally only, and to *disregard* relevant *global* information, that's not helpful.

Continuing the space complex thought demonstration:
When you step on a weighing scale, to weigh yourself, the readout says how much force your feet are exerting on the weighing scale, compressing that weighing scale.

When you were standing on the floor the floor was exerting a force upon you, maintaining your circumnavigating motion. As you stepped on the weighing scale the weighing scale has to provide that force.

The weighing scale is compressed due to your inertia.

Of course, we can move on to think of physics lessons to a group of students, with the instructor discussing the case of the period of a simple pendulum. For that local case, the swinging pendulum, it is of course sufficient to treat the G-load as an unspecified gravitational force.

The point is: depending on the situation you make an assessment whether it is sufficient to think locally only, or whether the assessment requires information of a more global character.

In the above I did not mention the expression 'frame of reference'. The expression 'frame of reference' is about attribution.

I find the expression 'frame of reference' awkward in the following sense: it is not a physical statement. I see some people write something along the lines of: "When you are in circumnavigating motion you are in a rotating frame of reference". I find that an unhelpful statement. In science, to make an assessment you gather relevant information. With the relevant information gathered you know whether you are in circumnavigating motion, or that the G-load that you feel is due to the gravity of a planet.

Answer (score -1):

There are two reasons why it is incorrect to describe pseudo-forces as a form of inertia:

1. Inertia is “the resistance of any physical object to any change in its velocity”. But a pseudo-force such as centrifugal force applies to all objects, including those that are travelling at a constant velocity.
2. Inertia is a property of an object. But the pseudo-forces that apply to an object depend on the frame of reference, and so cannot be a property of the object.